# Import text file separated by new line

Tags: r, data.table, sapply, rbindlist

Ultimately, I need to create the following table:

```
ID Age Gender
1  25  F
2  14  M
```

and so on. . .

I got my data in many txt files, where the ID is the name of the file.
Age and Gender are separated by new line, for example:

```
Age: 25
Gender: F
```

Now, I merge all the files into a one data table with the file path as the ID column (later I'll get rid of the whole path with stringr)

```
all_test <- list.files(path = "my/file/path", full.names=T)
dtt <- rbindlist( sapply(all_test, fread, simplify = FALSE, sep=":", sep2=" "),use.names = TRUE, idcol = "ID" )
```

And here is my problem - I'm getting the following table:

```
ID V1     V2
1  Age    25
2  Gender F
```

I tried using `sep = "\n"` but it did nothing. How can I tell R each variable is in a different line? (preferably with data.table)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible approach is to reshape into wide format with `dcast` and use `type.convert` to get the columns into the right classes:

```
DTnew <- dcast(DT, ID ~ V1, value.var = 'V2')[, (2:3) := lapply(.SD, type.convert), .SDcols = 2:3][]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > DTnew
>    ID Age Gender
> 1:  1  25      F
> 2:  2  14      M
>
> > str(DTnew)
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
>  $ ID    : int  1 2
>  $ Age   : int  25 14
>  $ Gender: Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 2
>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
>  - attr(*, "sorted")= chr "ID"
> ```

---

Example data:

```
DT1 <- fread('Age: 25
              Gender: F', sep = ':')
DT2 <- fread('Age: 14
              Gender: M', sep = ':')
DT <- rbindlist(list(DT1, DT2), idcol = 'ID')
```